# jQuery Cycle plugin - pause/resume weird behavior

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I have a slideshow running with the awesome cycle plugin, and when you click a button in the show, I show a hidden layer on the page and send a 'pause' command to cycle. I'm having two problems:

1. When the pause command is received, cycle immediately flips back to the 1st slide in the sequence (why??), and doesn't hit my before/after callbacks.
2. After closing the layer, I send a 'resume' command to cycle. The slideshow resumes (from the 1st slide, where the pause left it), but now cycle doesn't call my before/after callbacks at all, even as the slideshow progresses.

So I guess my question is: how can I properly pause/resume the slideshow so these strange behaviors don't occur? (And just to be completely clear and avoid any confusion, this isn't about the "pause on hover" feature, which is actually working fine for me. :-)

Here's my cycle() init, and my callback functions. (Why am I manually tracking the nextSlide, you ask? Because the built-in value for the current slide doesn't get updated properly for the before/after callbacks.)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
      fx: 'fade',        // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        timeout:       4000,  // milliseconds between slide transitions (0 to disable auto advance)
        speed:         1000,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value)
        pause:         1,     // true to enable "pause on hover"
        delay:         0,     // additional delay (in ms) for first transition (hint: can be negative)
        slideExpr:     'img',  // expression for selecting slides (if something other than all children is required)
        before:       moveArrow, // function to call when moving to next slide
        after:       upd, // function to call when moving to next slide
        fastOnEvent:   'fast',
    });
  });

  var nextSlide = 0;

  function upd(a, b, c) {
    nextSlide = nextSlide + 1;        // track which slide we're on
    c = $('#slideshow img').length;
    if(nextSlide > (c - 1)) nextSlide = 0;   // wrap back to 1st
  }

  // move indicator showing which slide we're on
  function moveArrow(a, b, c) {
    $('#slide-indicator').attr('class', 'c'+nextSlide);

    $(".clickmap").hide();          // hide other clickmaps
    $(".clickmap.c"+nextSlide).show();    // show map for this slide

    return true;
  }
```

Thanks for any thoughts on this--

best,
Eric

Comment: I'm having this issue too. I hope someone has an answer.

Comment: I figured out a hacky workaround that might also work for you-- but need help getting the workaround to play right. Argh :-) You can see my question about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295185/jquery-remove-function-attached-to-div

Comment: I'm getting closer-- I think part of the problem is some kind of problem with Mac Firefox. I set up a text page here with very simple code: http://themepark.com/eric/

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, pause and resume were not working. It appeared I had installed the lite version, with the full/complete version it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show your code for sending the pause command.  Something is definitely wrong there because pause does NOT reset the slideshow to the first slide.

Also, you don't need to keep track of the slide index yourself.  The third arg to the before/after callbacks is an options object that has the internal state of the slideshow.  On that object you will find 'currSlide' and 'slideCount' properties, among many others.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re: currSlide. I was using that before and was getting some strange results, but I just tried it again and it's fine now, so maybe I made a mistake previously.

Additionally, I did a bunch more testing and see part of what's going on. When cycle('pause') is called, all elements in the #slideshow div are set to "top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; display: none; opacity: 0" and the z-index of every element is reset as well.
 (cont'd)

Comment: This is causing some of the behavior I'm seeing: I have several layers on top of each other for the slideshow, so that explains the first slide reappearing.

Part of what's going on is that, inside my #slideshow div, I have other divs (that are not part of the slideshow but need to be in there), so when I set up cycle() I tell it to only pick the IMG elements inside of the #slideshow div. But I think on the 'pause' it's ignoring that and just resetting everything in there.

Comment: There are a few different things going on here and this thread is getting a little crazy, but FWIW I found an issue with Mac Firefox, which is probably helping explain at least some of the weirdness. Try http://themepark.com/eric from Mac Firefox...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I just had the same problem.  The way I got around it was to simply create my own function to pause and resume the slideshow with JQuery's hover events.

As Eric pointed out in a few comments, a related issue is that the plugin's pause option only allows hovering over the IMG element to pause the slideshow, so if you've got anything over your images, like a pager or any decorative elements, then you are boned.

So, I put my decorative elements, banner (which I called "#banner") and pager all into a div called "#banner-container" and then applied this code to fix my problem:

```
$('div#banner-container').hover(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('paused')){
       $(this).addClass("paused");
       $('div#banner').cycle("pause")
   }
},function(){
   if($(this).hasClass('paused')){
       $(this).removeClass("paused");
       $('div#banner').cycle("resume")
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the JQuery Cycle Plugin version: the "lite" version ignores the pause/resume commands. Using the full version could solve the problem.

EDIT: Sorry, i was wrong: i tried both versions but had the same issue using the full version.